# When is FirebaseFirestoreException thrown?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I wonder when the `FirebaseFirestoreException` is thrown? I read the doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) but cant see any explanation. I have run som test like disconnecting Internet but the evaluation:

```
if (e != null)
```

Is never true. I figure disconnecting internet will make the listener stop working and not fire the `Event` or `FirebaseFirestoreException` so when does it get thrown? Where can I read about this, code?

```
final DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF");
docRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot snapshot,
                        @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
        if (e != null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
            return;
        }

        if (snapshot != null && snapshot.exists()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Current data: " + snapshot.getData());
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Current data: null");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Aside from my answer, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-fix-firestore-error-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-777d591f404) will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have run som test like disconnecting Internet but the evaluation is never true.

When you are not connected to the internet, there is **no** exception that will be thrown, since Cloud Firestore is desigend to work offline. Writing or reading data to/from the Firestore database while you're not connected to the Firebase servers is **not** considered an error in any way. This is the default behaviour. An exception will thrown when for example, you perform a query that does **not** satisfy the rules that are set on the server. [Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) will always reject any queries that are not allowed, hence an exception will be thrown. The error message that you'll get looks like this:

> PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.